# session and PHP ( two site on localhost)

Tags: php

I am working on a website , everything worked good , but I maked a copy of my website (I run at localhost)

when I login at new site , the session created but , for old site ! I can easily login to old site with new site =))

my problem is here new site do not store (or find) the session , when I check with firebug , a new cookie created successfully.

how can I solv it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Same session variable for different systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790130/same-session-variable-for-different-systems)

Comment: Just put sites on different subdomains (one.localhost, two.localhost). Set up apache correct ways, and put host/ip to hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different `session_name(String)` for each site and before `session_start()`.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php